# how can I pass multipart form-data and file upload using graphql-ruby at serverside?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-ruby

below code is for mutation

```
field :companyUpdate, Types::CompanyType do
    argument :id, !types.ID
    argument :file, Types::FileType
    resolve -> (obj, args, ctx) {
      company = ::Network::Company.find(args[:id])
      company.update!(logo: args[:file])
      company
    }
  end
```

and file_type.rb is

```
    Types::FileType = GraphQL::ScalarType.define do
  name 'File'
  description 'action_dispatch_uploaded_file'
  coerce_input ->(action_dispatch_uploaded_file, ctx) {
    action_dispatch_uploaded_file
  }
end
```

it is not working. apollo client is using apollo-upload-client for uploading the file but it gives error as file is null.
what's the solution?

Answer (score -4):

Define a `File` type in your schema. submit the form normally!
In the server side, before sending data to `GraphQL resolver`, save the file and store change the variable!

something like [this](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-server).

**Update:**

Apollo Server 2 has file upload support! use [this article](https://blog.apollographql.com/file-uploads-with-apollo-server-2-0-5db2f3f60675) from Apollo in order to have file upload support in your backend:

Comment: I did not get can you explain little bit more? how can I store file before sending data to resolver? @mohsen-zarezardeyni